# Cannot iterate ES6 Map object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

I am working on a simple React project.
I have this Map object `books` with book.id as the keys and book object as the values. So i can create a Map object but I cannot iterate the Map use `for... of` or `forEach`.

This is part of the code

```
const books = this.props.readingBooks;

let KEYS = [];
let VALUES = [];
for (const book of books) {
    let [key, value] = book;
    KEYS.push(key);
    VALUES.push(value);
}
```

When i use the code up, i always have this error:

[image]

Comment: this error is because books isn't an array

Comment: `books` is not the `Map` object that you think it is. The error means that `books` is not an iterable, not something that a `for` loop knows how to iterate.  I'd suggest you do `console.log(books)` and see exactly what it is.

Comment: FYI, once you fix the contents of `books`, you can directly get the keys and values with `Array.from(book.keys())` and `Array.from(book.values())`.

Comment: hey @jfriend00, i have console.log(books) and I am  pretty sure it is a Map. Here is the result: `Map(2) {"sJf1vQAACAAJ" => {…}, "nggnmAEACAAJ" => {…}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write this in an answer because I need to show you some code even though we haven't yet quite figured out what's wrong with your code.

First off, the error you show means that some code is trying to iterate something that isn't an iterable.  If your assertion is correct that the error comes from the `for/of` loop, then it's telling you that `books` is not an iterable, therefore, not a Map object.

You can see with this simple example, that if `books` is a legit `Map` object, then your code works fine.  You can run it right here in this snippet and see that it works if `books` is a proper `Map` object.

```js
const books = new Map([["key1", "val1"], ["key2", "val2"]]);

let KEYS = [];
let VALUES = [];
for (const book of books) {
    let [key, value] = book;
    KEYS.push(key);
    VALUES.push(value);
}

console.log(KEYS);
console.log(VALUES);
```

So, either `books` isn't a proper `Map` object like you think it is or there is something else going on in your real code that you're not showing us here.

Comment: OMG!!! i finally figured it out. Everything was right except when I create the state in my app.js I set the `currentlyReading : {}` as an `Object` to hold the Map values. So when it passed to the child component, it will an object rather than the Map.

Really appreciate the help!!!!!!

Comment: @qmkiwi - Glad you figured it out.